# NodeJS and web sockets: Check if socket origin is the same as the web socket server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Edit: I'm sending data from app A to app B over web socket, where A is a router app for something else, and B is my web app. When B receives the data, it should send it to any client viewing its home page, also over web socket. But, since the roter app and the home page clients are connected to the same web socket server, I don't know which connections are to the clients viewing the home page, and which connections are to other stuff, like my router. Only the home page clients should receive the data.

I basically want to pass the logging data recieved from my router to my home page in real time so I can view it.

========

I have an express app that server a simple html page. It runs this script:

```
var host = window.document.location.host.replace(/:.*/, '');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + ':5000');
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
};
```

In the nodejs backend, I have a simple [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) server running, listening for connections:

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;

module.exports.init = function(server) {
  var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server });
  wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
    ...
  });
};
```

I get connections from, at the moment, 2 different locations.

1. A router app I have running that is sending this web app logging messages.
2. The html-page that this web app is serving.

I want to pipe the data from the router app to my html page, but to do that I need to know which of my connections I need to pipe the data to. I can in theory have many connection, but only one of them, at least for now, should be passed the data after it is recieved.

I thought I could compare the origin of the web socket connection to the domain of the web server the web socket server ran on.

I can get the origin of the connection like this: `ws.upgradeReq.headers.origin`. That will return e.g: `localhost:5000`. But I don't know the domain name where my web socket server is running. I've tried to google, and it seems like to get the domain name, I need to get it from an http request. What I am looking for is something that just gives me the name, without having to wait for an http request.

I've tried `os.hostname()`, but it doesn't give me the results I need.
I've also tried `server.address()`, where `server` is `var server = require("http").createServer(app);`, but that gives me this: `{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 5000 }`.

Isn't there just a way to get the host and port? Can I somehow use the `address` part above to get the host name?

The web app will probably run on Heroku.

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do.  I think you need to back up and describe the high level problem, not the solution you're trying to pursue.  I get that you have a nodejs server with a router that is presumably serving web pages.  I get that you have a webSocketServer in that nodejs process, presumably on a different port.  I don't understand what data you're trying to send from what to what.  Where does the data originate and where are you trying to send it?

Comment: I added the edit up to, tried to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your recent comments, it sounds like each browser client that connects a webSocket should just tell your server what web page it is looking at with an initial message and the server should keep track of that for each active connection.

In socket.io (built on top of webSockets), you could just connect to the `/homepage` namespace and then that server could broadcast to all sockets connected to that namespace.  You could, of course, implement that type of functionality yourself with a plain webSocket.

Then, your server would not only have a list of connected sockets, but could also know what page they were all from.  That would allow you to broadcast based on current page.  Your server-to-server webSocket would not have sent a message that it's from the home page, so it would not be tagged as such and you could avoid sending to it.

You might find socket.io easier to use for all of this.  In additon to namespaces on both client and server, it also gives you automatic reconnection from browsers, a simpler message passing system, server-side broadcast to namsepaces and so on.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. I'm kinda annoyed I didn't think of this straight of the bat, I was doing it so complicated. Namespaces would indeed by nice, but if use socket.io one place, I have to use it everywhere. I tried using ws and io together, but they didn't connect. Maybe I'll just switch out ws for io everywhere.

Comment: What if I add a third party script to the browser ,  which also listen to messages , how can I prevent this kind of attack ?

Comment: @Eris - If you have a new question (which it sounds like you do), then you should post a new question and include all relevant detail needed to understand the question and the situation.  Your two line comment doesn't contain enough info to even start to understand what you're asking or what the situation is that you want to protect.  Please start a new question with a lot more information in it.